# get xml node value from xml string

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml which contain xml namespace. i need to get value from its xml node

```
<personxml:person xmlns:personxml="http://www.your.example.com/xml/person" xmlns:cityxml="http://www.my.example.com/xml/cities">
<personxml:name>Rob</personxml:name>
<personxml:age>37</personxml:age>
<cityxml:homecity>
    <cityxml:name>London</cityxml:name>
    <cityxml:lat>123.000</cityxml:lat>
    <cityxml:long>0.00</cityxml:long>
</cityxml:homecity>
```

Now i want to get value of tag `<cityxml:lat>` as `123.00`

Code :

```
string xml = "<personxml:person xmlns:personxml='http://www.your.example.com/xml/person' xmlns:cityxml='http://www.my.example.com/xml/cities'><personxml:name>Rob</personxml:name><personxml:age>37</personxml:age><cityxml:homecity><cityxml:name>London</cityxml:name><cityxml:lat>123.000</cityxml:lat><cityxml:long>0.00</cityxml:long></cityxml:homecity></personxml:person>";
var elem = XElement.Parse(xml);
var value = elem.Element("OTA_personxml/cityxml:homecity").Value;
```

Error i am getting

```
The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name.
```

Comment: what about trying something like this 
`elem.SelectSingleNode("/cityxml:homecity/@value").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use XNamespace. For example:

```
XNamespace ns1 = "http://www.your.example.com/xml/person";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.my.example.com/xml/cities";

var elem = XElement.Parse(xml);
var value = elem.Element(ns2 + "homecity").Element(ns2 + "name").Value;

//value = "London"
```

Create XNamespace using a string that contains the URI, then combine the namespace with the local name.

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669152(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: how to get only `name` as `London` ?

Comment: @Shaggy var value = elem.Element(ns2 + "homecity").Element(ns2 + "name").Value;

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using a [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to navigate your xml.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//cityxml:homecity/cityxml:lat");
        string latvalue = null;
        if (node != null) latvalue = node.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error I got with your code was that there needs to be a namespace to parse the XML properly
Try :

```
 XNamespace ns1 = "http://www.your.example.com/xml/cities";
 string value = elem.Element(ns1 + "homecity").Element(ns1 + "name").Value;
```

I would still advice using XDocuments to parse if possible, but the above is fine if your way is a must.